# Most usual notation for extracted matrix

Tags: matrices, notation, terminology

Let $$A = \pmatrix{1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9}.$$

What is the most usual notation and english-math vocabulary term for *"the extracted matrix obtained by removing the 3rd line and 2nd column"*, i.e.

$$\pmatrix{1&3\\4&6}$$

Would you note it $A_{3,2}$, ${A^{(3,2)}}$, etc. ? I know there's probably no consensus, but what's the most usual notation you find in textbooks?

---

Example: This is useful when computing a determinant:

$$\det(A) = 7  \det A_{3,1} - 8 \det A_{3,2} + 9 \det A_{3,3}. $$

Comment: @Peter: not sure: `the "adjoint" of a matrix normally refers to its corresponding adjoint operator, which is its conjugate transpose.` (Wikipedia), so I don't think it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be an $m$-by-$n$ matrix with complex entries. If $\emptyset \subset \alpha = \{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{m'} \} \subseteq\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $\emptyset \subset \beta = \{\beta_1,\dots,\beta_{n'}\} \subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$, then the *submatrix of $A$ with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$*, denoted $A[\alpha,\beta]$, is the $m'$-by-$n'$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-entry is 
$$a_{\alpha_i\beta_j}.$$

In the example above, $\alpha = \{1,2\}$, $\beta=\{1,3\}$, and
$$A[\alpha,\beta] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{\alpha_1\beta_1} & a_{\alpha_1\beta_2} \\
a_{\alpha_2\beta_1} & a_{\alpha_2\beta_2}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{23}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
4 & 6
\end{bmatrix}.$$

If $\alpha = \beta$, then $A[\alpha,\alpha]$ is abbreviated to $A[\alpha]$.

Answer (score 2):

One calls it "the [*submatrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Submatrix) of $A$ obtained by removing row $3$ and column $2$."  Alternatively, you may write "the *submatrix* of $A$ obtained by deleting the third row and second column".

For the notation, there's no consensus:

- Wikipedia adopts the exclusive notation $M_{ij}$ which denotes the *determinant* of the submatrix of $A$ obtained by deleting the $i$-th row and $j$-th entry. $$M_{ij} = \det((A_{p,q})_{p \ne i, q \ne j})$$
  Wiki claims this notation to be "*standard everywhere in the litterature*".
- Some authors may prefer surrounding $M_{ij}$ by a pair of $|$'s to denote the *determinant*, so that $M_{ij}$ means the submatrix of $A$ obtained by deleting the $i$-th row and $j$-th entry. $$M_{ij} =(A_{p,q})_{p \ne i, q \ne j}$$ One example from Shayle R. Searle's [*Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=S-KODgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=matrix+algebra+useful+for+statistics+searle&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDj5qTu6XZAhXEEVAKHUWHCUEQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22let%20us%20denote%20the%20minor%22&f=false).

---

(Edit in response to OP's comment)

The author prefers to use $A_{ij}$ for the $(i,j)$-th partitioned matrix of $A$.  I extract the bottom of page 72 of the book to illustrate this.

> When matrices $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ are partitioned so that their submatrices are appropriately conformable for multiplication, the product $\bf AB$ can be expressed in partitioned form having submatrices that are functions of the submatrices $\bf A$ and $\bf B$.  For example, if
>   $$A = \begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}_{11} & {\bf A}_{12} \\ {\bf A}_{21} & {\bf A}_{22} \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad B = \begin{bmatrix} {\bf B}_{11} \\ {\bf B}_{21} \end{bmatrix},$$ then
>   $${\bf AB} = \begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}_{11} & {\bf A}_{12} \\ {\bf A}_{21} & {\bf A}_{22} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} {\bf B}_{11} \\ {\bf B}_{21} \end{bmatrix} 
>  = \begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}_{11} {\bf B}_{11} + {\bf A}_{12} {\bf B}_{21} \\ {\bf A}_{21} {\bf B}_{11} + {\bf A}_{22} {\bf B}_{21} \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Do the references you mention use $M_{ij}$ for $A$ (then it's not very handy to speak about the same thing for matrix $B$) or $A_{ij}$?

Comment: The author uses $M_{ij}$ for $A$ in the section where the word *submatrix* first appeared.  (c.f. the link to Google Books in my answer)  I think he wants to save $A_{ij}$ for [partition matrices](https://books.google.fr/books?id=S-KODgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=matrix+algebra+useful+for+statistics+searle&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDj5qTu6XZAhXEEVAKHUWHCUEQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22functions%20of%20submatrices%22&f=false).  (see the bottom of p.72)

Comment: Thanks again. What is a partition matrix? (Link not viewable on Android)

Comment: You may see the [related Wiki page on partitioned matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) for examples.

Comment: Oh right, this, thank you.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, [you should "accept" the answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/290189) by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).